# Order Items with Options Configurator

Tags: cartthrob

I have set up a T-Shirt with the Options Configurator field type named 'inventory_and_options' but can't work out how to display its selected item options in an invoice.

The products options are:

Size: Red, Blue

Colour: Small, Medium

I have created an order for a medium blue Tshirt.

My invoice code:

```
{exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="{entry_id}"}
    {item:title}<br>
    {item_options}
        Option Label = {option_label}<br>
        Option Name = {option_name}<br>
        Option Value = {option_value}<br>
    {/item_options}
{/exp:cartthrob:order_items}
```

This displays:

```
Great T-Shirt
Option Label = Inventory and Options
Option Name = Medium Blue
Option Value = sku-medium-blue
Option Label = Inventory And Options:size
Option Name = Medium
Option Value = Medium
Option Label = Inventory And Options:colour
Option Name = Blue
Option Value = Blue
```

So that has looped through all the item_options but all I want it to give me is:

```
Great T-Shirt
Size: Medium 
Colour: Blue
```

If I get rid of the item_options tag and hard code the fields created in the order items field in the orders channel..

```
{exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="{entry_id}"}
    {item:title}<br>
    {item:inventory_and_options}<br>
    {if item:inventory_and_options:size}Size: {item:inventory_and_options:size}{/if}<br>
    {if item:inventory_and_options:colour}Colour: {item:inventory_and_options:colour}{/if}<br>
{/exp:cartthrob:order_items}
```

Displays:

```
Great T-Shirt
sku-medium-blue
Size: Medium
Colour: Blue
```

Which is close but obviously causes a problem if I add other product options other than size and colour as I would have to manually update the template whenever I add a new product option.

Sorry for the rambling explanation, has anyone else had problems displaying   options in an invoice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `{if selected}{/if}` inside your `{item_options}` tag.

Comment: Oh my! I have been through the docs so many times but didn't see that before. I have just found some reference to {if option_selected}{/if} are there any differences in use?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this has actually solved my issue (although it did solve another issue I had in the cart). I still think I am going to have to hard code the Size and Colour titles in to the invoice because this data isn't actually stored in the order_items field in the order channel.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by Chris Newton making some tweaks to allow a sub_label tag..

```
    {exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="{entry_id}"}

                            {order_items}
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><b>{item:title}</b><br>
                                    <div>

                                        {item_options}
                                            {if sub_label}<i>{sub_label}: {option_value}</i><br>{if:else}<i>{option_label}: {option_value}</i><br>{/if}
                                        {/item_options}

                                    </div>

                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" align="right">{item:quantity}</td>
                                <td valign="top" align="right">{item:price_plus_tax}<br /></td>
                                <td valign="top" align="right">{item:subtotal_plus_tax}<br /></td>
                            </tr>
                            {/order_items}
{/exp:cartthrob:order_items}
```